# Install Centos on PC using only USB with LiveCD

Tags: linux, installation, centos, livecd

My laptop cd isn't working.  I have a USB which has Linux Live on it.

Am I able to use this to install a fresh copy of Centos on the laptop?

If so, how?

Comment: Try plugging it in to the laptop and booting.

Comment: @terdon.  Sorry for my stupid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving us a whole lot of information here, but if you have a bootable flash drive with CentOS Live on it, you should be able to reinstall the operating system from the boot menu.

If you are trying to install CentOS but don't have the CentOS bootable flash drive, several methods are described on CentOS's wiki page. Be sure to check out all of the solutions to see which is best for you.

Source: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/InstallFromUSBkey